# aiogram. Попасть в handler без сообщения пользователя

Tags: python, aiogram, handlers

Начинаю писать бота на aiogram.
Как перейти из функции new_type в new_comment без сообщения пользователя?
Т.е., если условие

> template in ds1 and str(answer).lower() == "нет"

не выполняется, то нужно присвоить состояние StateNew.StateNew9 и не ожидая от пользователя какого-то ответа/действия попасть в функцию new_comment, где в переменную answer записать, допустим, пустую строку

```
@dp.message_handler(state=StateNew.StateNew8)
async def new_type(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["access"] = answer
    data = await state.get_data()
    template = data.get("template")
    if template in ds1 and str(answer).lower() == "нет":
        await message.answer("Нужен изолированный стенд?\n"
                             "Для отмены нажмите /cancel")
    else:
        pass
    await StateNew.StateNew9.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=StateNew.StateNew9)
async def new_comment(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    if str(answer).lower() == "нет":
        await message.answer("Тогда укажите доступы\n"
                             "Для отмены нажмите /cancel")
        await StateNew.StateNew8.set()
    else:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data["type"] = answer
        await message.answer("Ваш дополнительный комментарий\n"
                             "Для отмены нажмите /cancel")
        await StateNew.StateNew10.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил кусок

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
            data["type"] = answer
        await message.answer("Ваш дополнительный комментарий\n"
                             "Для отмены нажмите /cancel")
        await StateNew.StateNew10.set()
```

В первую функцию после else

Comment: Для внесения исправления в вопрос, нажмите на править ниже вашего вопроса, а сам ответ удалите, т.к. он не является ответом